# Speech to Text using SpeechLib DLL Not Firing Recognition Event

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Here is my code, I am not familiar with SpeechLib Dll i have referred one website and i just tried.

I have already done speech to text application using System.Speech namespace. But there i couldn't get the 100% accuracy, so only i am just trying the possibilities available.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        wavRecoContext = new SpInProcRecoContext();
        ((SpInProcRecoContext)wavRecoContext).Recognition += new _ISpeechRecoContextEvents_RecognitionEventHandler(Program_Recognition);
        ((SpInProcRecoContext)wavRecoContext).Hypothesis += new _ISpeechRecoContextEvents_HypothesisEventHandler(Program_Hypothesis);
        ((SpInProcRecoContext)wavRecoContext).EndStream += new _ISpeechRecoContextEvents_EndStreamEventHandler(Program_EndStream);
        grammar = wavRecoContext.CreateGrammar(0);
        grammar.DictationLoad("", SpeechLoadOption.SLOStatic);
        inputFileStream = new SpFileStream();
        inputFileStream.Open("aboutus.wav", SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMOpenForRead, false);
        wavRecoContext.Recognizer.AudioInputStream = inputFileStream;
        grammar.DictationSetState(SpeechRuleState.SGDSActive);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static void Program_Hypothesis(int StreamNumber, object StreamPosition, ISpeechRecoResult Result)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static void Program_EndStream(int StreamNumber, object StreamPosition, bool StreamReleased)
    {
        grammar.DictationSetState(SpeechRuleState.SGDSInactive);
    }

    static void Program_Recognition(int StreamNumber, object StreamPosition, SpeechRecognitionType RecognitionType, ISpeechRecoResult Result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Result.PhraseInfo.GetText(0, -1, true));
    }

}
```

I couldn't able figure out what mistake i made here. 
If anybody had experience on this issue please give me solution.

Comment: How can you add SpeechLib in project references ? it's a COM but it's not appears in COM list.

Answer (score 1):

You're not selecting an SR engine.  In-process reco contexts need to specify both an audio source *and* a recognition engine.

I have some [C++ code to do this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2010/03/01/specifying-parameters-for-an-inproc-recognizer.aspx), but I haven't translated it to C#/SpeechLib.